change the time of the default wordpress crons
In WordPress this are some default crons as shown in the below image

how can we able to update the default time of this crons for next run?
Can we change using any hook ? Also can we change using WP-CLI ?
I tried to change using plugin and also checked documentation but that did n't work.

Which plugin? I'd have thought this was just editing some serialized data and so that would be hard to get wrong.

I'm surprised wp-cli cron doesn't let you edit scheduled times, but you can delete and reschedule.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/
